# Inserting a pdf file to a database and then downloading it on another computer

Tags: java, sql, blob

So I've managed to insert a pdf file into my database using BLOBS.
now if I would like to retrieve the pdf file on another computer using the same database but on a computer that doesn't have the pdf file downloaded how can I do that?
I would like to have it so that it starts a download for the pdf when a button is pressed.

The code down below I use to insert files into the database.

```
 btnBifogaFiler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            file.setCurrentDirectory(new 
File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new 
FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg", "gif", "png", "pdf");
            file.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            int result = file.showSaveDialog(null);

            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
                path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

                int i = path.lastIndexOf(".");

                String nyPath = path.substring(i, i + 4);

                lblBild.setText(nyPath);

                s = path;

            }

        }
    });




  try {
        PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 
FILER(FILID,FIL,TYP) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(s));
        selectedFile = file.getSelectedFile();
        path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

           extension = "";

            int i = path.lastIndexOf(".");

            extension = path.substring(i,i+4);

            textLabel.setText(extension);


            ps2.setInt(1,nyaVardet2);
            ps2.setBlob(2, is);
            ps2.setString(3,extension);
            ps2.executeUpdate();


           }
```

Comment: Typically databases are not great at storing large BLOBS. Consider storing the file in a directory somewhere and then just save a reference to it in your database.

Comment: As it stands your question is too broad since you want to: [1] Extract a blob containing a PDF file from a database [2] Download the content of that blob to some arbitrary machine as a PDF file. Those are distinct requirements that belong in separate questions. Can you reword your question to focus just on the first requirement? Also, as a related issue, your question shows no research effort - show your code where you have attempted to read the PDF from the database.